# powershell move-item based names only from csv and rename If it already exists based numbering

Tags: powershell, csv

I want to move folders from one location to another (according to the list of folder names in the CSV file).
If the name already exists then rename the folder that is passed with numbering and then move it.
I tried to create something based on a script that someone wrote here in the past but it is not that successful.
I will be happy to help.

```
$src = "C:\Users\Yaniv Naor\Desktop\users"
$dest = "C:\Users\Yaniv Naor\Desktop\oldusers"
$CsvFile = "C:\Users\Yaniv Naor\Desktop\Disable_users.csv"
$num=1

Import-Csv $CsvFile | select users |ForEach-Object {

Test-Path (Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Recurse |select name) }  |

 $nextName = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $_.name

 while(Test-Path -Path $nextName)

{
   $nextName = Join-Path $dest ($_.BaseName + "_$num" + $_.Extension)   
   $num+=1  
}

 $_ | Move-Item -Destination $nextName
}



ver2:

$src     = "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\users"
$dest    = "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\oldusers"
$CsvFile = "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Disable_users.csv"
$errorLog = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath ('{0:yyyy-MM-dd}_Errors.txt' -f (Get-Date))

#####################################################
# CHECK THE COLUMN NAME IN YOUR INPUT CSV
#####################################################
$userNames = Import-Csv $CsvFile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty users -Unique

# get an array of folders already in the destination. Names only
$destFolders = @(Get-ChildItem $dest -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)

# find the folders we're after and move them to $dest. Append a sequence number if the folder is already there
Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Directory | Where-Object { $userNames -contains $_.Name } | ForEach-Object {
    $count = 1
    $newName = $_.Name
    while ($destFolders -contains $newName) {
        $newName = "{0}({1}){2}" -f $_.BaseName, $count++, $_.Extension
    }
    $newFolder = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $newName
try {
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $newFolder -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    # update the $destFolders array with this new name for the next iteration 
    $destFolders += $newName
}
catch {
    Write-Warning "Error moving folder '$($_.FullName)'"
    # write something to the log. You can write the full error message in
    # $_.Exception.Message (or $Error[0].Exception.Message) if you like.
    Add-Content -Path $errorLog -Value "Error moving folder '$($_.FullName)'"
}
}
```

Comment: Show us part of your _sanitized_ input CSV. Does it have headers? Which column should correspond with the folder name?

Comment: If you want to move **folders from a list** your lines `Import-Csv` and `Test-Path` don't make any sense, iterating with a foreach without reflecting the currently processed item `$_` but instead doing a gci each time starting in $src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input CSV file looks anything like this:

```
"UserName","Email","DisplayName"
"jdoe","john.doe@yourdomain.com","John Doe"
"janedoe","jane.doe@yourdomain.com","Jane Doe"
"uknown","un.known@yourdomain.com","Un Known"
```

then below code should do it.

```
$src     = "C:\Users\Yaniv Naor\Desktop\users"
$dest    = "C:\Users\Yaniv Naor\Desktop\oldusers"
$CsvFile = "C:\Users\Yaniv Naor\Desktop\Disable_users.csv"

# throw an error if the $src folder does not exist
if (!(Test-Path -Path $src -PathType Container)){
    Throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] "The folder '$src' could not be found."
}
# create the destination path if it does not exist
if (!(Test-Path -Path $dest -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $dest -ItemType 'Directory' -Force | Out-Null
}

# get an array of user names from the CSV. These names should correspond with the folders in $src
#####################################################
# CHECK THE COLUMN NAME IN YOUR INPUT CSV 
# I'm using the 'UserName' column from my example Csv
#####################################################
$userNames = Import-Csv $CsvFile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName -Unique

# get an array of folders already in the destination. Names only
$destFolders = @(Get-ChildItem $dest -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)

# find the folders we're after and move them to $dest. Append a sequence number if the folder is already there
Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Directory | Where-Object { $userNames -contains $_.Name } | ForEach-Object {
    $count = 1
    $newName = $_.Name
    while ($destFolders -contains $newName) {
        $newName = "{0}({1}){2}" -f $_.BaseName, $count++, $_.Extension
    }
    $newFolder = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $newName
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $newFolder -Force

    # update the $destFolders array with this new name for the next iteration 
    $destFolders += $newName
}
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to keep track of any errors that may occur when moving the folders in a log file, you could do this:

Below the line `$CsvFile ='...'`, declare another variable for the path and filename of your errors log file:

```
# create a name for the errors logfile
$errorLog = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath ('{0:yyyy-MM-dd}_Errors.txt' -f (Get-Date))
```

Next, in the `ForEach-Object` loop, change these lines:

```
$_ | Move-Item -Destination $newFolder -Force

# update the $destFolders array with this new name for the next iteration 
$destFolders += $newName
```

to this:

```
try {
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $newFolder -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    # update the $destFolders array with this new name for the next iteration 
    $destFolders += $newName
}
catch {
    Write-Warning "Error moving folder '$($_.FullName)'"
    # write something to the log. You can write the full error message in
    # $_.Exception.Message (or $Error[0].Exception.Message) if you like.
    Add-Content -Path $errorLog -Value "Error moving folder '$($_.FullName)'"
}
```

If no errors occur, the error file will not be created. When something does happen, you can find the file in the destination folder: `2019-03-09_Errors.txt` (if it is created today). Errors are also written to the console using `Write-Warning`

Comment: Hi,
It's better than I expected. Another thing if possible
Report on folders that did not go through for any reason
thanks a lot!

Comment: @yanivnaor You're welcome. Please explain what you mean by _did not go through_. Do you mean folders that were not moved because they were not mentioned in the CSV perhaps?

Comment: No.
I mean the folders mentioned in the CSV file and yet they did not go through for some reason. (I have multiple sources of folders but one destination).

Comment: @yanivnaor I have edited the answer to add code for logging errors.

Comment: Hi, apologize for the response time (there was a problem with my account solved today). That's not exactly what I meant. I meant that if the folder name exists in the csv file but still did not reach the destination folder then the folder will be listed in the error file. I tried for example to write in a file a folder name that is not in the source folder and several more folders that exist. He passed on who he found but did not make errors file. maybe I did something wrong I will add the script as soon as I can. thanks for the all help!